# Store numbers that start with 0 in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Lets say I have stored in a sqlite database the following records as Strings:

```
09575788
08902149
08902134
47889789
47889776
47889797
48250496
```

My task is to check if these values exist in the database. So i have build one method that checks for the existence of these values.

So the user insert one of these value in the editText and I have to check if the value exists.

The problem that appears is that when I try to search for a number that start with "0" the query always returns null, but when I search for any other number - that doesn't start with "0" the query finds the value in db.

This is my code:

```
 Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY1, KEY2, KEY3},
                KEY_CONDITION1 + " LIKE " + prefix1 + " AND " + KEY_CONDITION2 + "=" + prefix2, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
```

Any idea how to solve? thanks for your answer

**IMPORTANT** All the values are stored as String in database

Comment: If the leading zero is significant then its not a number its a string so quote the value; `where fld = '09575788'`

Comment: yes, but are stored as Strings in database.

Comment: In the query (without the quotes) if you; `where fld=098765` your forcing a conversion of the field to a numeric type then looking for 98765

Comment: well I tried to cast it to int, but it can't find this way too!

Comment: String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(stkIdEditText.getText().toString()));

Comment: so `+ " AND " + KEY_CONDITION2 + "='" + prefix2 + "'"` fails for 0* ?

Comment: but fails this query too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14279/discussion-between-adrian-and-alex-k)

Answer (score 3):

@Adrian, the correct answer was given to you by Alex K, but you have misunderstood him, I think.  If the leading zero is meaningful (e.g. as it would be for a US zip code that can begin with a zero) then you do not have a number, rather you have a string. The data affiliation of such a column should be text (aka varchar). You do not want to cast the value with a leading zero to an integer; you simply want to look for the string value by wrapping the search term in single quotes; for example:

```
          ...  where zipcode = '01287'
```